# Perl-compatible regular expressions to match upper case ",", space and "(" ")"

Tags: regex, qt5, pcre

I am trying to remove the `SQL` statements from a `QString`. All the `SQL` instructions are upper case. I want to have only the column names which are all lowercase with underscore as space in their names. As a sample the `QString` might contain:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activated_alerts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date_and_time TEXT, system_state TEXT, alarm_no_185 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_4 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_5 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_2 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_102 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_7 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_27 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_120 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_103 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_190 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_30 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_31 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_32 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_33 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_34 BOOL NOT NULL, alarm_no_35 BOOL NOT NULL)
```

I tried `^[A-Z]+$` but I'm getting zero matches.

```
QRegularExpression re("^[A-Z]+$");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(m_activatedAlertsSQLStatement);
if(match.hasMatch()) 
{
    qDebug() <<  "CAPTURED: " << match.capturedTexts();
}
```

Comment: Remove the anchors "^" and "$" and use globalMatch() of QRegularExpressionMatchIterator class.

Comment: @lbarros it only finds the first upper-case word `CREATE`.

Comment: Use QRegularExpressionMatchIterator class to match all possible matches

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatchiterator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
[^\WA-Z]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH3uU9/1). The pattern simply matches 1 or more word characters that are not uppercase ASCII letters.

Qt sample demo:

```
QRegularExpression re("[^\\WA-Z]+");
QString subject("YOUR_STRING");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(subject);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    qDebug() <<  "CAPTURED: " << match.captured(0); // Print match value
    //...
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).